# What may cause a crash in apple background queue in release configuration only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-log

The application i'm currently debugging crashes only when it's built under release configuration. And what is more surprising it crashes in apple background queue. Take a look at this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Crashed Thread:  9
```

and this:

```
Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-priority
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x340102be CFRelease + 18
1   CoreFoundation                  0x340106fc CFRelease + 1104
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3bdb0484 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 164
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c1cf9cc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 360
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c1cfabc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c1ffa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c1ff8a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Can anybody give me a hint? What may cause such a crash?

Comment: This is often caused by compiler optimizations. You may have some code that is undefined behavior and runs fine under `-O0` but crashes on higher optimizations.